# Microsoft Prism-based solutions

Tags: prism

What is the value of "Design View Model" in Prism-based solutions? MS documentations says that it is option and indeed when I commented relevant part in the code, everything was just fine. So what is the value added then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have in mind a design-time sample data (that can be encapsulated inside a view model as well). This is helpful when building your UI in Visual Studio designer or in Blend.

Your controls and views can look significantly different without data. To help you visualize the final result of your design you can provide some sample, design-time data, to see how the layout will look when the application is running.

See more details on MSDN [Guildelines for Desgin-Time Sample Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098(v=pandp.40).aspx#GuidelinesforDesignTimeSampleData)